# ADBFS-rootless functionality query

Tags: android

I have ADBFS-rootless working on my ununtu VM as I can peruse the filesystems on my Android phone. The thing I have noticed is that I cannot access files with root only perms _rw______. Is this normal behaviour or should I be able to access such files a password.key.

Regards

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Android, like any other unix-like system, will only allow file access if your user or group has permissions to the file, so the question comes down to if your access will occur as root, or not.

On a secured device such as a typical consumer phone, the ADB daemon on the device - and thus all access run through ADB - runs as the "shell" account.  This account has somewhat greater privileges than a typical application's user account (for example it can install packages, take screenshots, etc) however it is still not the superuser or root account, and cannot generally access private files of applications or on recent builds (regrettably) even *read* large parts of the system installation.

On an emulator or engineering device (including some aftermarket ROMs), ADBD runs as root, or can be made to do so using the "adb root" command.  When ADBD runs as root, your ADBFS system can presumably access anything root can.

In an aftermarket ROM or "rooted" device where ADB does not run as root, there may be a hacked "su" executable available which can start a root shell.  If ADBFS is able to use that, it might be a solution.  Otherwise, you may be able to use the root shell to somehow get ADBD restarted as root, but that may be a bit tricky.